# Function for unpacking RGB point field from point in point cloud?

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found an example in the codebase that uses some messy bit-twiddling to get the individual r,g,b fields out of a packed rgb float.  Is there a nice utility function for doing this?

(I'm trying to avoid unnecessary copy-pasting)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9126/function-for-unpacking-rgb-point-field-from-point-in-point-cloud?/) by [mattbell](https://answers.ros.org/users/129/mattbell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-02-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mattbell](https://answers.ros.org/users/129/mattbell/) on 2011-02-27**:
Here's what I ended up doing:       uint32_t rgb_val_;
memcpy(&rgb_val_, &(cloud_rgb->points[i].rgb), sizeof(float));

```
    uint8_t r_ = (uint8_t)((rgb_val_ >> 16) & 0x000000ff); 
    uint8_t g_ = (uint8_t)((rgb_val_ >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
    uint8_t b_ = (uint8_t)((rgb_val_) & 0x000000ff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sample code on http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud provides two ways to do the reverse. Shouldn't be too hard to flip it around.

In C++,

```
int rgb = 0xff0000; 
float float_rgb = *reinterpret_cast(&rgb);
```

In Python,

```
float_rgb = struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('i', 0xff0000))[0]
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1